# How to use NGXS with Angular Route Resolvers?

Tags: angular, ngxs

I am implementing NGXS in my Angular App, where I am trying to dispatch actions through the route resolver. With my current implementation, it is calling the same HTTP requests every time on route change.

How can I prevent Router Resolver from making duplicate HTTP Requests? I have added an extra key in my state `isUserDataLoaded` but as I am new in NGXS I am confused about how I can use it to prevent making duplicate HTTP Requests.

**Action.ts**

```
export class GetCurrentUser {
    static readonly type = '[CurrentUser] Get';
}
```

**State.ts**

```
interface IUserState {
    currentUser: ISpotifyUser | null;
    isUserDataLoaded: boolean;
}

@State<IUserState>({
    name: 'currentUser',
    defaults: {
        currentUser: null,
        isUserDataLoaded: false
    }
})
@Injectable()

    export class CurrentUserState {
        constructor(private _spotify: SpotifyService) {}
    
        @Selector()
        static getCurrentUser(state: IUserState) {
            return state.currentUser;
        }
    
        @Selector()
        static isUserDataLoaded(state: IUserState) {
            return state.isUserDataLoaded;
        }
    
        @Action(GetCurrentUser)
        getUserDetails(ctx: StateContext<IUserState>) {
            return this._spotify.getCurrentUser().pipe(
                tap((apiResult) => {
                    ctx.setState({
                        currentUser: apiResult,
                        isUserDataLoaded: true
                    });
                })
            );
        }
    }
```

**Resolver.ts**

```
resolve(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<any> {
        return this._store.dispatch(new GetCurrentUser());
}
```

Comment: this case use with graphQL?